# Comparing words from file against a list much too slow

Tags: python

I am looking to write a function that takes a list of words (wordlist), opens a txt file and returns a list of words that don't appear in the txt file. This is what I have so far...

```
def check_words_in_file(wordlist):
    """Return a list of words that don't appear in words.txt"""
    words = set()
    words = open("words.txt").read().splitlines()

    return [x for x in wordlist if x not in words]
```

The problem I am having with this function is that it is too slow. If I use a wordlist consisting of say 10,000 words, it takes about 15 seconds to complete. If I use one with 300,000 it takes way longer than it should. Is there anyway I can make this function faster?

Comment: Please try to choose descriptive titles in the future. If everyone with a Python question used "Programming in Python" as their title, we'd have almost 350,000 questions with that same title, and nobody could find anything.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with your understanding of usage of variables and associating with objects, which is evident when you write

```
words = set()
words = open("words.txt").read().splitlines()
```

In the first line, you initially create an empty set object and associate the reference of it with the variable `words`. Later you open the file and split the lines of it content, which returns a list and rebind the variable `words` with the list

You probably intended to write

```
words = set(open("words.txt").read().splitlines())
```

**Further improvement**

You can actually do better, if you create a set of the arguments `wordlist` and find an asymmetric set difference

```
words = set(wordlist).difference(open("words.txt").read().splitlines())
return list(words)
```

**Nitpick**

It is generally not advised to open a file and let the file handle be garbage collected. Either close the file or use a context manager

```
with open("words.txt") as fin:
    from itertools import imap
    words = set(wordlist).difference(imap(str.strip, fin))
    return list(words)
```